# Basic units in Python doesn't run graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to run this code(Below) that try to run 4 graphs in a single image help to run it please:

But I'm receiveing this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basic_units'
```

code:

```
from basic_units import cm, inch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cms = cm * np.arange(0, 10, 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axs[0, 0].plot(cms, cms)

axs[0, 1].plot(cms, cms, xunits=cm, yunits=inch)

axs[1, 0].plot(cms, cms, xunits=inch, yunits=cm)
axs[1, 0].set_xlim(3, 6)  # scalars are interpreted in current units

axs[1, 1].plot(cms, cms, xunits=inch, yunits=inch)
axs[1, 1].set_xlim(3*cm, 6*cm)  # cm are converted to inches

plt.show()
```

Comment: [basic_units](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_downloads/0f0fd288c7d4a6a16f4835b96343f597/basic_units.py)

Comment: You can't import a module that you don't have....

Comment: How do I install basic_units?